# Spring boot Batch - MongoItemReader - Not reading Document when run again

Tags: mongodb, spring-batch

I am using SpringBatch with a MongoItemReader:

```
 @Bean
 MongoItemReader<> myReader() {
     reader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
     reader.setCollection("MyCollection");

     Map<String,Sort.Direction> sort= new HashMap<>();
     sort.put("_id",Sort.Direction.ASC);

     reader.setSort(sort);
     reader.setTargetType(MyTarget.class);
     reader.setQuery(mongoQuery);
     
     return reader;
}
```

I am calling the batch via a restController endpoint. When I run the batch the first time, the document gets picked up and everything is fine. When I run the batch is run again, the document even though it matches the criteria, does NOT get picked up.

Interestingly when I restart the batch, the document gets picked up again! Something tells me somehow MongoItemReader is storing this information, because if I use a FileReader, the same thing does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared does not show when the `reader` is instantiated and if it is managed by Spring or not.

Spring beans are singletons by default, and your reader bean seems to be defined as a field in the enclosing class and probably injected as a singleton. You need to create a new instance of the reader in the bean definition method, something like this:

```
@Bean
public MongoItemReader<MyTarget> myReader() {
   MongoItemReader reader = new MongoItemReader();
   reader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
   reader.setCollection("MyCollection");
   Map<String,Sort.Direction> sort= new HashMap<>();
   sort.put("_id",Sort.Direction.ASC);
   reader.setSort(sort);
   reader.setTargetType(MyTarget.class);
   reader.setQuery(mongoQuery);
   return reader;
}
```

This should work, but the issue persists, then you would need to make the bean step-scoped so that a new Spring bean is creared for each job execution:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public MongoItemReader<MyTarget> myReader() {
   MongoItemReader reader = new MongoItemReader();
   reader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
   reader.setCollection("MyCollection");
   Map<String,Sort.Direction> sort= new HashMap<>();
   sort.put("_id",Sort.Direction.ASC);
   reader.setSort(sort);
   reader.setTargetType(MyTarget.class);
   reader.setQuery(mongoQuery);
   return reader;
}
```